# C# How to store bytes into Uint32 array

Tags: c#, byte, uint32

I have an UINT32 array filled with bytes, because my value is too long it has to be in uint32 because byte array is just to short for it

```
UInt32[] somebytes = new UInt32[] { 0xAABBCC, 0xAABBCC };
```

but whats inside is `0x00AABBCC, 0x00AABBCC`

and because of that my function that should return first 2 bytes in every row

```
[0] = 0xAA
[1] = 0xAA
```

returns

```
[0] = 0x00
[1] = 0x00
```

here is my function, that should return first 2 bytes (my brain tells me that first 2 bytes are 0xAA)

```
public byte[] GetRed(UInt32[] buffer)
{
    byte[] output = new byte[buffer.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < output.Length; i++)
    {
        byte b = (byte)buffer[i];
        output[i] = (byte)(b & 0xFFFF);   //fist 2 bytes
    }
    return output;
}
```

I hope someone has an idea, on whats going on and how to fix all this
Thsnk

Comment: The first byte of `0x00AABBCC` is `0x00`, not `0xAA`. Why not store your values in a `byte[]` and not worry about endian-ness and everything else that you get with multi-byte integral types. Otherwise, learn how to do bit sizzling with shifts and masks.

Comment: you have a few problems here. First, as Flydog pointed out, the first byte of `0xAABBCC` is `0x00` when it is stored in a `UInt32` variable. But also, your bitmask is wrong and your cast to `byte` is cutting off the data you want. the bitmask `0xFFFF` will select the opposite of what you want (`0xBBCC`) so you need to do `b & 0xFF0000` and then you need to right shift it 16 bits so that the data is in the LSBs when you cast to `byte` So your whole operation would be `(byte)((b & 0xFF0000) >> 16)`

Comment: because I am storing pixels in this array (each pixel can have red,green,blue color (0xFFFFFF = white)

Comment: @frankM_DN thanks, that did the trick, (I guess I should practise bit manipulations a bit, its always so confusing, you write your bitmask on paper (you turn on all the bits you want to omit, but for some reason its still wrong :) )

BTW: why did you shift by 16 instead of 32? (isnt uint32 32bits, so if you want to move your desired bits to the most right (LSB, you shift by 32?)

Comment: @LimetaPeta, shifting right by 32 bits would shift all of the bits in a `UInt32` out and you would just be left with `0`! If we look at `0x00AABBCC`, `AA` is in bits 16 - 23 and you need them in bits 0 - 7 (so that they can be put into a `byte` variable. So that means we need to shift right 16 bits.

Comment: Here's the most complex example of bit swizzling I can think of. It might give you some ideas (my answer) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55499116/c-sharp-extract-bit-ranges-from-byte-array/55505757#55505757