# Interpreter Pattern on Byte Array

Tags: c#, arrays, bitwise-operators, interpreter-pattern

I´ve got an byte array where variouse bits have a meanings. Now I´m wondering if I should use the interpreter pattern to define the array´s meaning and the pattern builds some dto´s out of the definition.

```
new Interpreter(arr)
  .Interpret("B0.01", ref MyObject.MyValue)
  .Interpret("B0.02", ref MyObject.SecondValue);
```

I´m unsure if its the best solution. May someone tell if there is a similiar project on the net or maybe a better solution? I´m using C# .net-framework 4.6.1

[EDIT]

For example I´ve got the following Byte-Array

```
var arr = new[] { 0b00010010, 0b11100101, aso...}
```

Now a documentation may say:

```
Byte 0, Bit 0 -> Person has blue hair
Byte 0, Bit 1 -> Person owns a house
Byte 1, Bit 7 -> The house is gray
```

Now I want parse from this array maybe two objects as following

```
public class Person 
{
    public bool HasBlueHair { get; }
    public bool OwnsHouse { get; }
}

public class House 
{
    public bool IsGray { get; }
}
```

I thought maybe the [interpreter pattern](https://www.dofactory.com/net/interpreter-design-pattern) is a good solution for this purpose but I´m not very familiar with it, so I need some help.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow you: what is "bits have a meaning?", what is "interpreter pattern" in context of your problem? Could you, please, provide *some examples* of input data and the desired outcome? For instance, having `byte[] array = new byte[] {0x0A, 0x0B, 0x00, 0x12}` what is the desired result?

Comment: This is not a suitable problem for the *Interpreter Pattern*.

Comment: Can a sequence of bits be tokenized into an expression in a self-contained manner, or can the sequence be tokenized only with the help of the expected content as defined in the docs?  If the latter, this looks more like serialization, with the documentation defining a serialization contract for the data.

Comment: Generally, you do this with logical bit operations (possibly with a `[Flags]` enum)

Comment: This (my answer to a loosely related question) may provide some inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55499116/c-sharp-extract-bit-ranges-from-byte-array/55505757#55505757